# I can't somehow sort my linked queue nodes with a bubble sort algorithm

Tags: c++

So, I was asked by my instructor to make a node containing a few variables and sort it by taking the hourlySalary variable as reference for each code. However, there seems to be a problem with the outputs. It isn't sorting the nodes at all. I tried to fix it for a while and gave up. Looked up some sources on the internet but still no luck. I am guessing that the problem is somewhere in the swapping function or the bubble sort function.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myNumberIsEleven{
    private:
    
  struct linkedlist{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    unsigned int age;
    char gender;
    int hourlySalary;
    linkedlist *linker;
  }*Ptr,*curPtr;

public:
    int counter=0;

myNumberIsEleven(){
    Ptr=NULL;
}
void printList(){
    curPtr=Ptr;
    while(curPtr!=NULL){
        cout << curPtr->firstName << " " << curPtr->lastName << endl << curPtr->age << endl << curPtr->gender << endl << curPtr->hourlySalary << endl << "=====" << endl;
        curPtr=curPtr->linker;
    }
}

void add(int salary,string name,string lastname,int ageisjustanumber,char Gender){
    linkedlist *newPtr = new linkedlist;
    newPtr->hourlySalary = salary;
    newPtr->firstName = name;
    newPtr->lastName = lastname;
    newPtr->gender = Gender;
    newPtr->age = ageisjustanumber;
    newPtr->hourlySalary = salary;
    newPtr->linker = Ptr;
    Ptr = newPtr;
    counter++;
}

void Swap(linkedlist* a,linkedlist* b){
            string temp_firstName;
            string temp_LastName;
            unsigned int temp_Age;
            char temp_Gender;
            int temp_hourlySalray;


            temp_firstName = a->firstName;
            temp_LastName = a->lastName;
            temp_Age = a->age;
            temp_Gender = a->gender;
            temp_hourlySalray = a->hourlySalary;


            a->firstName = b->firstName;
            a->lastName = b->lastName;
            a->age = b->age;
            a->gender = b->gender;
            a->hourlySalary = b->hourlySalary;


            b->firstName = temp_firstName;
            b->lastName = temp_LastName;
            b->age = temp_Age;
            b->gender = temp_Gender;
            b->hourlySalary = temp_hourlySalray;
}

void bubbleSort(){
    
    for(linkedlist* i=Ptr;i->linker != NULL;i=i->linker){
        for(linkedlist* j = i->linker;j!=NULL;j=j->linker){
            if(i->hourlySalary > i->hourlySalary){
                Swap(i,j);
            }
        }
    }
    printList();
}


/*  
  void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)    
     
    // Last i elements are already in place
    for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
}
  */
  
};

int main()
{
    myNumberIsEleven myNameIsBerkan;
    myNameIsBerkan.add(1000,"berkan","iwontgivemysurname",21,'M');
    myNameIsBerkan.add(2100,"ah","be",31,'F');
    myNameIsBerkan.add(50,"uhmmm","something",10,'M');
    myNameIsBerkan.add(69000,"elon","musk",44,'M');
    myNameIsBerkan.bubbleSort();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: look closely at `i->hourlySalary > i->hourlySalary`. Longer identifier names might help make problems more visible

Comment: You are swapping two pointers. That does nothing useful whatsoever. When you sort a linked you need to carefully adjust the links.